# iOS prevents video recording in the event of low battery

Tags: ios, video-capture, batterylevel

My video recording app encounters a problem in the even of low battery on my device. It works perfectly until the battery level drops down to 20% or below. Is there any way to avoid this, and continue the video recording process?

Comment: Would your users appreciate it if you drain the last bit of their battery?

Comment: Well, I thing yes :). App needs to do some work and battery is secondary thing.

Answer (score -1):

Apple doesn't allow you to disable the "Low Battery" alert.  Make a [suggestion to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) and if they get enough feedback about this, they will think about adding an API.